# use greasemonkey/tampermonkey to write simple data to "cloud" (probably something like pastebin)

Tags: text, cloud, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm using Tampermonkey to collect data from pages I visit and store it locally and persistently across browser sessions.  This is working fine.  However, I'm limited to using the script on the same computer.  I'd like to be able to use the same script on another computer and update the same collected data file.

I'd like to use the simplest method possible to read, edit, and store a single text file from multiple computers.

An actual functioning "Hello world!" script would be fantastic.  I've mucked around with the pastebin API, but all the help applies to php code and there seems to be a lot of somewhat confusing overhead.  I don't need to examine the contents of the pasted data in a useful editor.  The data is never to be interpreted as code or html.  I don't need an SQL database.  This is just a project for fun, so I don't need to worry about privacy issues or elegant, modular code.

I just need a place to stash some bytes, and change them frequently.

What's the simplest solution?

Comment: What about github gist API? You can probably use wrappers like [this one](https://github.com/michael/github) (see [Gist section](https://github.com/michael/github#gist-api) for examples) or implement the access [yourself](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/).

Comment: @wOxxOm You'd probably need to roll your own since you need `GM_xmlhttpRequest` to avoid same origin policy.